# Spreadsheet publication require login for TSV/CSV

Tags: csv, google-sheets

I've using Google Spreadsheet publication for several years, but last week it stopped forking for some reason. Let me explain:

There are several public links for same ID:

```
1) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/<id>/pubhtml
2) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/<id>/pub?gid=12345&single=true
3) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/<id>/pub?gid=12345&single=true&output=tsv
```

- 1 - entire spreadsheet, HTML form
- 2 - just one list (sheet) with gid 12345
- 3 - just one list (sheet) with gid 12345, at TSV format (tab separated values).

**Links 1+2** are working fine. Public access like CURL, Google Chrome anonymous window.

**Link 3** stopped working. It throws 302 redir to Google account login page.

What I've tried

- republish (un-publish and publish again), ID remains the same btw.
- republish with more time delays between each step
- wait several hours
- CSV instead TSV (same result)
- discuss this with Google support (G.Suits).

---

If you want to see wget difference:

**Link 3** (302 redir to login)

```
Resolving docs.google.com... 2a00:1450:4007:808::200e, 216.58.215.46
Connecting to docs.google.com|2a00:1450:4007:808::200e|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=...
```

---

**Link 2** (literally same link with `&output=tsv` removed from the end).

```
Resolving docs.google.com... 2a00:1450:4007:808::200e, 216.58.215.46
Connecting to docs.google.com|2a00:1450:4007:808::200e|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: “pub?gid=12345...
```

I assume that this is a bug on Google side. But I may be wrong. Do you have any tips or familiar experience since last few days? I have this unchanged document on drive for 2+ years, linux curl script also unchanged, but today I fount them broken. Thanks

Comment: I am having this same issue. It is definitely causing issues with my workflow.

Comment: It looks like they found a work around here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64902111/publish-to-web-on-google-sheets-not-working-properly

Answer (score 0):

Just writing this up, as it was answered in one of the comments. In order to continue using your Publish to Web for CSV/TSV, you'll need your file to be publically accessible, until Google either undoes their change to permission requirements or fixes the issue at hand.

This means you'll need to go into any files you want to Publish, and ensure that you have the
[image]
setting set.

Some have reported that you need to republish once you've changed the permissions, which I cannot confirm or deny, as I simply republished my sheets anyway. This solution worked for me, I hope it works for you.